# Is Rust hash map storing the same key twice?

Tags: rust

I am going through the Rust language book, and was going through the [hash map](https://rust-book.cs.brown.edu/ch08-03-hash-maps.html) section.
At the end of the section there is a quiz, which asks what would be the output of the following code.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
fn main() {
    let mut h: HashMap<char, Vec<usize>> = HashMap::new();
    for (i, c) in "hello!".chars().enumerate() {
        h.entry(c).or_insert(Vec::new()).push(i);
    }
    let mut sum = 0;
    for i in h.get(&'l').unwrap() {
        sum += *i;
    }
    println!("{}", sum);
}
```

The answer is 5, and I confirmed by executing the same. The explanation given is following

> This program stores a vector of indexes for each occurrence of a given letter into a hashmap. Then it sums all the indexes for the letter 'l', which occurs at indexes 2 and 3 in the string "hello!".

Now when I look at section [adding a new key](https://rust-book.cs.brown.edu/ch08-03-hash-maps.html#adding-a-key-and-value-only-if-a-key-isnt-present) and [updating value based on old one](https://rust-book.cs.brown.edu/ch08-03-hash-maps.html#updating-a-value-based-on-the-old-value), it seems Rust only allows unique key for a hash map as per definition.

However, when I run the above program with an extra print statement in the for loop

```
for i in h.get(&'l').unwrap() {
    println!("{}", i);
    sum += *i;
}
```

It seems there are two entries for the character `l`. As per my understanding, when iterating over string `hello!` when the first for loop encounters the second `l` it should update and overwrite the index value of `l` from 2 to 3, instead of making another entry with key `l` and value 3.

So the question is, is Rust allowing duplicate keys? Somehow this is not making sense.

Comment: What output are you seeing, and what is the expected output?

Comment: There is only one entry for `'l'`. That entry is a vector of length 2, which is equal to `vec![2, 3]`.

Comment: Your HashMap type is `<char, Vec<usize>` and finally your HashMap looks like `{'e': [1], 'o': [4], 'l': [2, 3], 'h': [0], '!': [5]}`. If `l` is found it adds its index to the vec at the key `l`.

Comment: Damn I am an idiot, who did not see, that the value is a vector. Thanks @BallpointBen and Nick I am marking this as resolved.